# Move global .vscode folder and update path in VScode

Tags: python, conda, visual-studio-code

So vscode placed a .vscode folder in the path "C:\Users\Owner" by default. Inside that folder is another folder called "extensions".  I believe this is where my global extensions are stored. I don't like the location so I would like to move it to a more suitable path "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Roaming\Code\User.vscode". The question is: How do I update the path in vscode (or otherwise) so that it points to the new location by default instead of regenerating a new .vscode folder in "C:\Users\Owner"? I've dug around user settings and there seems to be no straightforward way of achieving this.

There are also a .python, .anaconda, .conda, .matplotlib folders automatically generated in the "C:\Users\Owner" folder. Why are these folders created here and is there something I need to change to prevent these folders from being automatically generated here?

Looking forward to your help. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't.  It's really irrelevant whether you like the location or not, that's where it goes.  It's the equivalent of the HOME path in Unix.

Comment: @Tim Roberts Thanks for your response. If anyone else knows how to achieve this please chime in.